# Gawk matching one word - one unexpected match

Tags: awk

I wanted to get all matches in Column 3 which have the exact word "aa" (case insensitive match) in the string in Column 3
The gawk command used in the awk file is:

```
$3 ~ /\<aa\>/
```

The BEGIN statement specifies: **IGNORECASE = 1**
The command returns 20 rows. What is puzzling is this value in Column 3 in the returned rows:

**aA.AHAB**

How do I avoid this row as it is not a word by itself because there is dot following the first two aa's and not a space?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact word"? `aA` in `aA.AHAB` is a *whole* word. If `$3` must be equal to `aa`, use `$3 ~ /^aa$/ `

Comment: `$3~/^aa$/` might work (didn't test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` is a word character. `.` is not a word character. `\>` matches the zero-width string at the end of a word. Such a zero-width string occurs between `A` and `.`.

To search for the string `aa` delimited by space characters (or start/end of field):

```
    $3 ~ /(^|[ ])aa([ ]|$)
```

Add any other characters that you care about inside the set (`[ ]`).

Note that by default, awk splits records into fields on whitespace, so you will not get any spaces in `$3` unless you have changed the value of `FS`.

Comment: It worked. Have  understood how the Regular expression above works and the flexibility it offers.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***1st solution:*** OR to exactly match `aa` try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $3 ~ /^aa$/' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** OR without `IGNORECASE` option try:

```
awk 'tolower($3)=="aa"' Input_file
```

Comment: `IGNORECASE` works on any string comparison and regex match.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:** Why does the awk regex-pattern `/\<aa\>/` matches a string like: "aa.bbb"?

We can quickly verify this with:

```
$ echo aa.bbb | awk '/\<aa\>/'
aa.bbb
```

The answer is simply found in the manual of gnu awk:

> **3.7 gawk-Specific Regexp Operators**
>
> GNU software that deals with regular expressions provides a number of additional regexp operators. These operators are described in this section and are specific to gawk; they are not available in other awk implementations. Most of the additional operators deal with word matching. For our purposes, **a word is a sequence of one or more letters, digits, or underscores (‘_’)**:
>
> - **`\<`:** Matches the empty string at the beginning of a **word**. For example, `/\<away/` matches `"away"` but not `"stowaway"`.
> - **`\>`:**
>     Matches the empty string at the end of a **word**. For example, `/stow\>/` matches `"stow"` but not `"stowaway"`.
>
> **<sub>source: [GNU awk manual: Section 3 :: *Regular Expressions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp)</sub>**

So to come back to the example from above, the string "aa.bbb" contains two words "aa" and "bbb" since the <dot>-character is not part of the character set that can build up a *word*. The empty strings matched here is the empty string before "aa.bbb" and the empty string between the characters `a` and `.` (an empty string is really an empty string, length 0, 0 characters, commonly written as `""`)

Solution to the OP: Since `FS` is most likely the default value, the field `$3` cannot have a space. So the following two solutions are possible:

```
 $3 ~ /^aa$/
 $3 == "aa"
```

If the field separator `FS` is defined in the code, the following might work

```
" "$3" " ~ /" aa "/
$3 ~ /(^|[ ])aa([ ]|$)       # See solution of JHNC
```